# How to take screenshot in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, screenshot, android-constraintlayout

I have recently started using `ConstraintLayout` and am loving it. But have come across a problem to be solved. Need to take a screenshot of a part view of the layout and that is easy in relative or linear layout as we make a layout around the view needed screenshot which is not the case in `ConstraintLayout`.

This is my view  :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sharable_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_streak_best"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/total_distance_steps_left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/total_distance_steps_right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/streak_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:max="360"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_gradient_bg"
        android:secondaryProgress="360"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/streak_bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_streak_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/clr_5d"
        android:textSize="58sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/streak_progress"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/streak_progress"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/streak_progress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/streak_progress"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35" />

    <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBITextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_streak_count_days"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/day_streak"
        android:textColor="@color/clr_5d"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/streak_progress"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/streak_progress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_streak_count" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/streak_goal_icons_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tv_streak_count_days"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/tv_streak_count_days"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_streak_count_days">


    </LinearLayout>
... more code here
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now I wish to take screen shot of the progressbar and few elements below it. I tried to create a view around it and take screenshot of that but it doesn't work. What can be done to take the screenshot?

Comment: Can u please elaborate more, do u want to take screenshot programmatically?

Comment: hide/remove everything that does not need to be placed in the screenshot, and take it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko no other way?? as there are many elements which needs to be removed.

Comment: you any way need them to be removed...

Comment: is that the only way to take screenshot in constraint layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
tools:visibility="gone"
```

to hide the view as below

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/sharable_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_streak_best"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/total_distance_steps_left_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/total_distance_steps_right_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:visibility="gone" />
```

add below as attribute at root view

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: this gives a blank view screenshot as there is nothing in the view.

Comment: write this line at particular view whom you want to hide, and for whom you need to show keep visibility visible for them

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. in to take screenshot we need a layout which helps up take the screenshot. and in ConstarintLayout we do not have such layout if we want to take screenshot of only few elements in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to hide/show your view

```
private void captureScreen(View v) {
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(extr, "fff" + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream f = null;
    try {
        f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, f);
        f.flush();
        f.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Screen", "screen");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

pass your `view` to above function

```
captureScreen(view you want to take a screen shot);
```

Comment: I know how to take the screenshot, but what view to pass in constraint layout as all the views are in the same parent.